# Can class type info MACRO be replaced with templates?

Tags: c++, templates, refactoring, c++17

I have a traditional large class inheritance tree (domain classes) that implements it's own class type info and registry. The way it is done is that each class 'calls'
a macro like this

```
class MyClass : public MyParent {
  MY_DECLARE_DYNAMIC(MyClass)

  ...
};

//in .c file:
MY_IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(MyClass, MyParent)
```

Basicly these macro's inserts a static function that is a meyer's singleton returning a pointer to `MyClassInfo` that looks like this:

```
class MyClass : public MyParent {
    MyClassInfo* GetClassInfo_() {
      static MyClassInfo instance=...;
      return &instance;
    }

    virtual MyClassInfo* GetClassInfo() const;
};
```

The other thing that gets inserted by the macro is a virtual function to retrieve class info for runtime use (ie. from some base type pointer).

`MyClassInfo*` holds a string name for the class and some way of getting the parents class info (implementation currently uses a function pointer for this).

This info may now be used by writing directly: `MyClass::GetClassInfo_()` or `myClass.GetClassInfo()`

In the real case there are (as you may have guessed) more details, but I think this is enough to illustrate the concept, except to say each class can have a little bit more traits like data (eg. an enum value indicating if this particular class is deprecated)

This pattern is also well known from WxWidgets and MFC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ywz9k63y(v=vs.140).

Does anyone have a solution for getting rid of these MACROs ? Apart from writing everything by hand - for example using templates or virtual inheritance etc. Prefereably one that doesn't add to the size of each object (more than the one virtual function).

Comment: Maybe through [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude wouldn't that spoil the currently used class heirachy ? (not even considering the number of instantiations would explode fairly quickly)

Comment: *"`MyClassInfo*` holds a string name for the class"*. Macro is the only way to handle string from token :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reasonable and simple way to make the code a lot nicer is just to move the static instance of `MyClassInfo` out of the class entirely, and make it a templated function:

Here's a full-ish example:

```
#include <type_traits>

class MyClassInfo {
public:
    virtual ~MyClassInfo() {}
    virtual MyClassInfo* get_parent() const = 0; 
};

template<typename T>
MyClassInfo* get_class_info();

template<typename T>
class MyClassInfo_impl : public MyClassInfo {
public:
    using parent_t = typename T::parent_t;
    MyClassInfo* get_parent() const override {
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<parent_t, void>) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        else {
          return get_class_info<parent_t>();
        }
    }
};

template<typename T>
MyClassInfo* get_class_info() {
    static MyClassInfo_impl<T> impl;
    return &impl;
}

class Parent {
public:
    // Could probably be inferred through SFINAE instead.
    using parent_t = void;
};

class MyClass : public Parent {
public:
    using parent_t = Parent;
    virtual MyClassInfo* GetClassInfo() { 
      return get_class_info<MyClass>();
    } 
};

int main() {
    auto class_info = get_class_info<MyClass>();
}
```

This way, you are only left with the virtual function, which, as you mentioned in the comments, becomes really messy to deal with with any inheritance-based solution.

Answer (score 1):

One more implementation, with hierarchy over the template wrapper. I'm using RTTI to obtain class name, this can be avoided by passing name into constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

struct class_info {
    const char* name;
    const class_info* parent;
};

template<class C>
constexpr const char* class_name() noexcept
{
    return typeid(C).name();
}

class object
{
protected:
  constexpr object() noexcept
  {}
public:
  virtual class_info* get_class_info() {
        static class_info _instance = {"object",nullptr};
        return &_instance;
  }
};

template<class Base,class Derived>
class reflective:public Base {
    reflective(const reflective&) = delete;
    reflective& operator=(const reflective&) = delete;
protected:
    constexpr reflective() noexcept:
        Base()
    {
        static_assert( std::is_base_of<object,Base>::value && std::is_base_of<Base,Derived>::value , "Base must inherit object, and Derived must inherit base" );
    }
public:
    virtual class_info* get_class_info() override {
        static class_info _instance = {::class_name<Derived>(), Base::get_class_info() };
        return &_instance;
    }
};

class offspring_0 :public reflective<object,offspring_0> {
public:
    constexpr offspring_0() noexcept:
        reflective<object,offspring_0>()
    {}
};

class offspring_1 : public reflective<offspring_0,offspring_1> {
public:
    constexpr offspring_1() noexcept:
        reflective<offspring_0,offspring_1>()
    {}
};

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {

    std::shared_ptr<object> offspring = std::make_shared<offspring_1>();
    const class_info *ci = offspring->get_class_info();
    std::cout << "Self name: " << ci->name << std::endl;
    unsigned i = 1;
    for(ci = ci->parent; ci != nullptr; ci = ci->parent) {
        for(unsigned j=0; j < i; j++)
            std::cout << '\t';
        std::cout<< "parent " << i << " name: " << ci->name << std::endl;
        ++i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Self name: 11offspring_1
        parent 1 name: 11offspring_0
                parent 2 name: object

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.084 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename base_class, type_name crtp_class>
class h_traits{
public:
    using this_type=crtp_class;
    using base_type=base_class;
    using traits_class=h_traits;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<base_class, typename base_class::this_type>, "invalid hierarchy");
    //Rest of definitions follows
    //...
};

class object_base//grand common base
{
public:
    using this_type=object_base;
    //... 
};
//...
class my_new_class: 
   public h_traits<my_old_class, my_new_class>
{
    //...
};
```